# Make database in appengine by eclipse

Tags: google-app-engine, windows-phone-8

I'm making a game for windows phone. And my game has a highscore board which gets value from appengine. 
And I'm finding a document to do that.
I want to know how to make a database and how to send, get value.
Can you give me a link or example ?

Answer (score 2):

You could look at [Mobile Starter Backend](https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/) that will give you a ready to use mBaaS hosted on App Engine with a generic data structure to store things like high scores, leaderboard, etc. Though the documentation mentions iOS and Android clients, you can also invoke the REST endpoints stuff from your Windows Phone code.

If you wish to roll out your own services, take a look at Google Cloud Endpoints that will give you a REST API hosted on App Engine and you can build in Datastore support. Start over here : https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/

Comment: Thanks Romin, I check it out.